# different host entries according to connected network

Tags: network-manager

I have the problem that a host is to be connected to with an internal IP when in a specific wifi network and otherwise with its public available IP
Is there a way to create a hosts entry only for one connection or something similar ?
My system is a ubuntu focal desktop with NetworkManager